# Convert haml js to slim

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, slim-lang

I'm trying to convert a haml template to slim. The view includes javascript. I am getting an error saying expected closing '}' when accessing the slim view that was generated using haml2slim. How can I convert the js below to working in slim?

_.haml

```
:javascript
  var client = new Client({
    projectId: "#{ENV['...']}",
    readKey: "#{..::ReadKey.new(
                  ENV['..'], {
                  filters:  [{
                    property_name: "account_id",
                    operator: "eq",
                    property_value: @account.id
             }]}).encrypt!}"
  });
```

haml2slim

```
javascript:
  | var client = new Client({
    | projectId: "#{ENV['...']}",
    | readKey: "#{...::ReadKey.new(
                  | ENV['...'], {
                  | filters:  [{
                    | property_name: "account_id",
                    | operator: "eq",
                    | property_value: @account.id
             | }]}).encrypt!}"
  | });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the colon should come **after** `javascript` like this:

```
javascript:
  var client = new Client({
    projectId: "#{ENV['...']}",
    readKey: "#{..::ReadKey.new(
                  ENV['..'], {
                  filters:  [{
                    property_name: "account_id",
                    operator: "eq",
                    property_value: @account.id
             }]}).encrypt!}"
  });
```

Comment: Thats how it appear from haml2slim but doesn't work. I will update the code with the haml2slim output above.